# Proof of Itô isometry in Øksendal (Lemma 3.1.5): why such an approximation approach?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-explanation, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I quote *Øksendal (2003)*.

> **Itô integral.** Let $\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{V}(S,T)$ be the class of functions $f(t,\omega):[0,\infty)\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $(t,\omega)\to f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{F}$-measurable (where $\mathcal{B}$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty)$), $f(t,\omega)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted and $\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{S}^T f(t,\omega)^2 dt\bigg]<\infty$.
>  [...] For functions $f\in\mathcal{V}$ we will now show how to define the Itô integral $$\mathcal{I}[f](\omega)=\int_{S}^{T}f(t,\omega)dB_t(\omega)$$
> where $B_t$ is $1-$dimensional Brownian motion. 
>  [...]
> The idea is natual: First we define $\mathcal{I}[\phi]$ for a simple class of functions $\phi$. Then, we show that each $f\in\mathcal{V}$ can be approximated by such $\phi$'s and we use this to define $\int fdB$ as the limit of $\int\phi dB$ as $\phi\to f$.
> Recall that a function $\phi\in\mathcal{V}$ is called elementary if it has the form $$\phi(t,\omega)=\sum_j e_j(\omega)\cdot\chi_{[t_j, t_{j+1}]}(t)$$
> **Lemma (Itô isometry).** If $\phi(t,\omega)$ is bounded and elementary then $$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(\int_{S}^{T}\phi(t,\omega)dB_t(\omega)\bigg)^2\bigg]=\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_{S}^T\phi(t,\omega)^2dt\bigg]\tag{1}$$
> [...] The idea is now to use the isometry $(1)$ to extend the definition from elementary functions to functions in $\mathcal{V}$. We do this in several steps:
> **STEP 1.** Let $g\in\mathcal{V}$ be bounded and $g(\cdot,\omega)$ continuous for each $\omega$. Then there exists elementary functions $\phi_n\in\mathcal{V}$ such that $$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_S^T(g-\phi_n)^2dt\bigg]\to 0\text{ as }n\to\infty\tag{2}$$;
> **STEP 2.** Let $h\in\mathcal{V}$ be bounded. Then there exist bounded functions $g_n\in\mathcal{V}$ such that $g_n(\cdot,\omega)$ is continuous for all $\omega$ and $n$, and $$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_S^T(h-g_n)^2dt\bigg]\to0\tag{3}$$;
> **STEP 3.** Let $f\in\mathcal{V}$. Then there exists a sequence $\{h_n\}\subset\mathcal{V}$ such that $h_n$ is bounded for each $n$ and $$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_S^T(f-h_n)^2dt\bigg]\to0\text{ as }n\to\infty\tag{4}$$
> That completes the approximation procedure. [...] If $f\in\mathcal{V}$ we choose, by STEPS 1-3, elementary functions $\phi_n\in\mathcal{V}$ such that $$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_S^T|f-\phi_n|^2dt\bigg]\to0\tag{5}$$Then define $$\mathcal{I}[f](\omega)=\int_{S}^{T}f(t,\omega)dB_t(\omega)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_S^T\phi_n(t,\omega)dB_t(\omega)\tag{6}$$

---

My question is:

> > why are those three STEPS necessary so as to get to $(5)$? In other words, which is the rationale of each of those three STEPS? Why has one to follow each of them so as to get to state that each $f\in\mathcal{V}$ can be approximated by such $\phi$'s? 
> > Could you please detail your answer step-by-step?

Comment: Such rationale is similar to the construction of the Lebesgue measure. Just like you have step functions there, we have elementary functions here. These go on to approximate bounded continuous functions, which approximate bounded functions, which approximate general functions. The point of starting with elementary functions is that you want the largest class of starting functions for which the way of defining the integral is intuitively well understood and easily expressible. Just like how with the Lebesgue measure where we start out with intervals.

Comment: These 3 steps are not given to prove or extend the Ito isometry (Oksendal is not extending (1) with these 3 steps). The steps are to extend the definition of the stochastic integral. He define the integral first for simple integrands and then he extend it to more general integrands. This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329807/approximating-a-general-process-by-a-simple-process-in-definition-of-integration

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I edit my question. Thank you a lot to both @UBM

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Those need to be different steps, because they are different stages of approximation ,which cannot be skipped, and each of these steps requires a different kind of proof in itself. These need to be three STEPS, rather than one JUMP, if you like.

Comment: Pardon @TeresaLisbon, why, in the second step, bounded and continuous functions are used so as to approximate bounded functions? Wouldn't it be enough to use bounded (not necessarily continuous) functions in order to approximate bounded functions?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing I will think about it.

Comment: OK, thank you @TeresaLisbon